# Mesh seems to still be proportionally editing even though it is turned off

Tags: mesh

I was following a tutorial that was talking about using proportional editing. I have proportional editing set to disable currently but whenever I try to drag a vertice or extrude an edge it keeps moving other parts of the drawing. Is there another setting or parameter I may have tweaked on accident that is doing this. Would love some help. Am completely stumped.

[image: really weird is when i try to extrude and it acts as though it's dragging a new face and pulling the other faces.]

[image: proportional editing is off yet it pulls the other vertices]

Comment: Could be from having your subsurf modifier set to show the editing cage, hard to say. Upload your file to http://pasteall.org/blend/ and add the link.

Comment: Uploaded it. Here you go. Thank you so much for the help. Not sure what the subsurf modifier is but I will look into it.  http://pasteall.org/blend/34528

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the [*Subsurf* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Subsurf) on your object, that is why your model appears so smooth and you have set it to show the cage or its **active effect** while editing. The modifier might have been accidentally added as the shortcut is simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>0 - 5</kbd> for each smoothing level (higher number being more subdivisions). If you want to disable this, delete it from the object or if you want to stop the "proportional editing effect", untick the triangle icon on the modifier.

[image]

*When doing organic modeling, having the cage on is often useful to see the changes in realtime when tweaking loops or filling faces as opposed to tabbing in and out of edit mode and object mode to the the updates.*

Since you have the cage enabled, it will show how the subsurf modifier is deforming the mesh as you work with it, if you are in the early stages of modeling and inexperienced, it's probably a good idea to keep this off until you have the general shape of your model in place and work with the flat "boxy" mesh. Reason being the modifier can produce exaggerated results that differ from when you look at the smoothed and unsmoothed model. The subsurf modifier will effectively "shrink/round" the mesh as it tries to create smoothed surfaces.

To see what I mean, add a cube and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> to add a subsurf modifier with 1 subdivison level. Play with the object with the cage on and then disable the modifier to see how it has changed the underlying structure of your object.

[image]

Comment: Oh thank you so much. This was the culprit. I really appreciate the help and all the effort you put in to solving this. I hit the up arrow and the check mark, anything else I can do?

Comment: @Brendan Finish the model. :) Further material on mesh topology for helping - http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/learning-mesh-topology-collection/